# Node.js can't use external css file

Tags: css, node.js

I recently start learning node.js, and I got problem. I use express to acces my public file, everything work fine except css files. I did some research on the topic, and use everthing i found, but it dose not work.

My folder structure

```
    app.js
    pub
     index.html
     style.css
```

This is my html:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html > 
 <head>
   <title> Curriculum Vitae </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
      <body>
       ...
   </body>
 </html>
```

And my app.js file:

```
    var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(path.join('pub', 'public')));

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: have you tried using SASS or Less ?

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is on this line :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join('pub', 'public')));
```

You are setting "/pub/public" as public folder, and you just need to set "/pub"

Can you try with something like this ?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pub'));
```

Hope it helps.